# When should I use “inasmuch” vs “inasmuch as”?

Tags: grammar, adverbs, conjunctions

I am wondering whether it is possible to use “inasmuch” without “as” right after. Consider the following sentences:

*This paper agrees with author (year), inasmuch it reaches a similar conclusion.*

*This paper agrees with author (year), inasmuch as it reaches a similar conclusion.*

I am wondering whether one is correct while the other one isn’t, or whether both are correct. So, in other words:

**Can I use “inasmuch” instead of “inasmuch as”? If no, when should I use the former and when should I use the latter?**

Comment: If you consider *inasmuch as* conveys "in **as much as**," you need the second *as*. But "agrees with" and "reaches a similar conclusion" are the same. All you need is "This paper agrees with the conclusion of author (year). "

Comment: I don’t understand why the question is closed. I just want to know whether I can generally use ‘inasmuch’ instead of ‘inasmuch as’. I just gave a sentence that was meant to be an example.

Comment: See [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inasmuch%2Cinasmuch+as&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3) comparing frequency of occurrence for both ***inasmuch*** and ***inasmuch as***. The fact that they're both about equally common clearly shows that there are next to no written instances of ***inasmuch*** that *aren't* followed by ***as***. I certainly can't think of any valid context where you could omit ***as***.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments!

Comment: It's exactly the same with my preferred alternative [***insofar as***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=insofar%2Cinsofar+as&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) EXCEPT the full Oxford English Dictionary has a separate entry (with usage citation) for ***insofar*** as well as ***insofar as***, but they have no separate entry or citations for ***inasmuch*** without ***as***. Partly because of that inexplicable (to me) difference, I'm voting to reopen the question.

Comment: No, it is not possible, unless you want to employ an obsolete usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of *inasmuch* without *as* means *likewise*, and that usage left the building with Alexander Pope (1688–1744). The *OED* labels it *obsolete*:

> **inasmuch** *adv.*
>  <sup>. . .</sup>
> **II.**
>  Without *as*.
> **II.3.**
>  † In an equal or like degree, likewise. *Obsolete.*
>  <sub>1732   The wisest Man that ever was, and inasmuch the
> richest, beyond all peradventure, was a Jew. (A. Pope, *Strange
> Relation E. Curll* in J. Swift et al., *Misc.: 3rd Volume* ii.
> 47)</sub>
>
> <sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary* —
> *inasmuch*](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/inasmuch_adv) (login required)</sub>

If you were to use it any anyway, you would need to use it as you might use *likewise*. Maybe:

> *This paper agrees with author and inasmuch reaches a similar conclusion.*

Answer (score 1):

I searched the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) for `inasmuch *`:

| phrase | count |
| --- | --- |
| INASMUCH AS | 1211 |
| INASMUCH , | 9 |
| INASMUCH THAT | 4 |
| INASMUCH THEN | 3 |
| INASMUCH IT | 2 |
| INASMUCH HE | 2 |
| INASMUCH WE | 1 |
| INASMUCH THE | 1 |
| INASMUCH FOUNDATION | 1 |
| INASMUCH FEMALE | 1 |
| INASMUCH ALSO | 1 |
| INASMUCH A | 1 |
| INASMUCH 20TH | 1 |

Almost all the hits are for "inasmuch as" (including some in the second row which were interrupted by commas). I would not use "inasmuch" unless followed by "as".